# Element not intractable Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make an auto bump program for forums but I can't seem to interact with anything.

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://ogusers.com/member.php?action=login")

#Login
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name("textbox")
inputElement.send_keys("xKyle")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really tell where problem lies, you need to say exactly what is happening, let's start with not giving selenium path to ChromeDriver. You need to download it from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), make sure to get driver compatible with your browser verison. 
Next give path to it, if you are on windows path will look like:

`r"C:\dir\dir\chromedriver.exe'`

you need to give 'r' for raw data, otherwise interpreter will think that you are trying to give some weird in-string command like \n for new line

Also try not to search by class name, for 99% of time you want to use Xpath, especially if it's relative. So just click on element, and copy xpath.

For more answers you need to tell exactly what are you trying to do and when it fails :)